# Loading scripts with document.write in an extension's content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

If a script contains:

```
document.write("<iframe>ads here</iframe>");
```

If it's included in the html before the page is requested for load, it might look something like this:

```
<html>
<!-- stuff !-->
<div><script src="document_write.js" type="text/javascript"></script></div>
<body>
</html>
```

Loading an html page with the code similar to above will result in the `<iframe>` being placed in the `<div>` tag which housed the script. If the `document.write()` is called after the page load, it will overwrite the whole page.

Chrome extensions' content scripts will also overwrite a page with `document.write`, or crash it - depending on when in the lifecycle of a page it was called.

Is there a way to insert scripts containing `document.write()` in Chrome's content scripts?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `document.write()` in a content script?

Comment: I would prefer not to, but it's very common for 3-rd party scripts like ads and trackers.

Comment: Have you tried using the `content_scripts` **[`runt_at`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#run_at)** attribute ?

Comment: I have; the time at which the JS i wish to insert runs doesn't really seem to solve the issue. I can't run a document.write with a script before HTML has even loaded - even if it did, that's certainly not where I want to place the resulting <iframe> code or some such

Comment: Sorry, it is not exactly clear what the problem is and what you are trying to achive. (This is probably due to my luck of experience when it comes to ads, trackers etc.)

Comment: Do you have access to modify those scripts that contain `document.write()` calls (or do you have to use them "as-is") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced the same problem when I was working with some conversion tracking scripts on my ajax site. I ended up overriding document.write, which fixed the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.write = function(str) {
        var moz = !window.opera && !/Apple/.test(navigator.vendor);
        if (str.match(/^<\//))
            return;
        if (!window.opera)
            str = str.replace(/&(?![#a-z0-9]+;)/g, "&amp;");
        str = str.replace(/<([a-z]+)(.*[^\/])>$/, "<$1$2></$1>");
        if (!moz)
            str = str.replace(/(<[a-z]+)/g, "$1 xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'");
        var div = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "div");
        div.innerHTML = str;
        var pos;
        if (!moz) {
            pos = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            pos = pos[pos.length - 1];
        } else {
            pos = document;
            while (pos.lastChild && pos.lastChild.nodeType == 1)
                pos = pos.lastChild;
        }
        var nodes = div.childNodes;
        while (nodes.length)
            pos.parentNode.appendChild(nodes[0]);
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of testing for opera and safari?

Comment: This is a generic override, which I got from John Resig's blog [http://ejohn.org/blog/xhtml-documentwrite-and-adsense/]

Comment: I see. The blog says that this solution doesn't work for IE - is it still true for "newer" IE9+ ?